# If $X_1,...,X_n$ are Bernoulli(p) iid then $X_1+...+X_n$ is Binomial(p,n)

Tags: probability

How can I prove that if $X_1,...,X_n$ are iid $Bernoulli(p)$, then $X_1+...+X_n$ is $Binomial(n,p)$ ?

---

**Attempt**

$$\mathbb P\{X_1+...+X_n=k\}=\sum_{x_1+...+x_n=k}f_{X_1,...,X_n}(x_1,...,x_n)$$
$$=\sum_{x_1+...+x_n=k}f_{X_1}(x_1)...f_{X_n}(x_n)$$
But now, I have difficulty to conclude. How can I do ?

I also did by induction, and it worked, but I really would like to use this method.

Comment: Just as a general tip if you ever need to find the distribution of a sum of i.i.d. random variables, moment/probability generating functions are usually the way to go

Answer (score 1):

On $$A=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in \{0,1\}^n\mid x_1+...+x_n=k\},$$  $$f_{X_1}(x_1)...f_{X_n}(x_n)=p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$
Therefore,

$$\sum_{A}f_{X_1}(x_1)...f_{X_n}(x_n)=p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\sum_{A}1=\binom{n}{k} f_{X_1}(x_1)...f_{X_n}(x_n).$$